# how do I move a row from one tab in a google sheet to another in the same sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am super new (as in this is my first stab at anything code related) to this...

I've read a bunch of similar questions and I have watched several videos related to the specific thing I am trying to do. I thought it would be simple, but it keeps failing and I cannot figure out why!

I am trying to set it up so that when a checkbox in the row is checked (which currently automatically happens when a value is 0 in another cell), that entire row gets moved to bottom of the list in a different sheet tab within the same spreadsheet and deleted from the first sheet tab.

I know about filtering and every other simpler option, but for what we are doing, it won't work right. It needs to move.

The error I keep getting says: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plC4L.png)

TypeError: Cannot read property 'columnStart' of undefined
at onEdit(Move Row When Paid:4:51)

Here is what I have (pic also attached): [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iifli.png)

```
function onEdit(e) {
const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
const r = e.range;
if (src.getName() != "Open Invoices" || r.range.columnStart != 11 || r.range.rowStart == 1) return;
const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Closed Invoices");
src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,12).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,12));
src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
```

}

I can link the spreadsheet if needed! All help is appreciated for this noob :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Open Invoices" && e.range.columnStart == 11 && e.range.rowStart > 4 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast('Flag1');
    const dest = e.source.getSheetByName("Closed Invoices");
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 12).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

Here's was my sheet looks like:

[image]

I don't have your headers so it does not work below line 5

Comment: It did not work, however I noticed something on my original one that I messed up and don't know how to correct and might be the cause of error. I need it to start looking on row 5. Rows 1-4 are header rows. Here is the spreadsheet...there's no actual data on it yet, just me playing around to try and make things work. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cY_O4wdG_oljHXswVq2gZ1afrgmKACteRdqkq4yUeQo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I tested it and it worked for me.  I changed the starting row to row 5

Comment: Mine says An unknown error has occurred, please try again later.

Comment: I can't help you with unknow errors.  But it still works for me.

Comment: This is going to sound dumb, but how are you testing it? I might be testing it wrong. This is literally the first time I've used Apps Script. I am clicking "Run" on the Apps Script Editor. Is that right? Sorry, I might just be way in over my head here and need to source this out to someone more knowledgeable lol.

Comment: I save the file and go to the checkboxes and click one of them

Comment: I look for Entry and Flag1 Toasts

Comment: Yeah you cannot run onEdit functions without supplying the event object

Comment: Your checkboxes are in the wrong column and they need to start in row 5

Comment: I figured it out!! I made a new test doc and messed with it until I got it. I think I can transfer that to my actual sheet now. THANK YOU so much!